# VBA automate file download using Internet Explorer 11

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, automation

I know this question has been answered many times for older versions of Internet Explorer, but I am having trouble finding an answer for IE 11.

I am trying to automate a file download from Internet Explorer 11. I have code to access the site, log in and generate the download request, but I am stuck on how to select "Save" when the download dialogue bar comes up (See image).

[image]

I've read through this very good tutorial but it was done on IE 8/9. When I check for the "File Download" window it isn't found so maybe the handle (hWnd) has changed? I am not comfortable enough in other coding to get the hWnd for that element.
http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/10/23/vbavb-netvb6click-opensavecancel-button-on-ie-download-window/

Comment: that type of programing is for quick dirty way to solve a temporary problem. you can not count on it neither maintain it. i suggest you take a look at Wininet functions. the right way to do internet programing in windows and specially for VB/VBA programers.

Answer (score 2):

I have a macro that download a file from Internet Explorer as well, I dont use your IE version but I may works

```
SendKeys "{F6}", True
SendKeys "{TAB}", True
SendKeys "{ENTER}", True
```

Comment: I have been looking for this for so long !! This was the only piece I missed in order to fully automate a huge code ! Thanks so much

Comment: I was desperately looking for a solution that do not require admin rights to change security level in corporate environment. 'F6' was the missing bit of information. Now I just have to ensure the IE window is active while I send the keys.

Answer (score 0):

Try...

```
SendKeys "{TAB}{TAB}{ENTER}"
```

Answer (score -2):

I wasn't able to work out the Wininet for this specific website, but figured out a workaround using Chrome via Selenium Wrapper which allows you to automate functions in Chrome/Firefox very similar to Internet Explorer. Chrome downloads automatically go to the Downloads folder so it circumvented having to work with that dialog box.

Comment: @skypjack - this is not a random "thank you", it's the OP explaining how they got a workaround for their problem.  So it's a legitimate attempt to answer.